# Google Analytics events sent from backend. not showing up

Tags: java, google-analytics

Hi I am very new to GA so please bear with me. I have set up a Universal property and added the tags in frontend, and in backend, which is Java, for some specific requests being handled I call this function

```
private void sendEventMetrics(EventHit eventHit, GoogleAnalytics metricTracker) {
    if (metricTracker != null) {
        GoogleAnalyticsResponse response = metricTracker.event().eventCategory(eventHit.eventCategory())
                .eventAction(eventHit.eventAction())
                .eventLabel(eventHit.eventLabel())
                .eventValue(eventHit.eventValue())
                .send();
    }
}
```

my frontend is

```
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>
```

When I debug backend, I see that the `response` is `200`, i also see different users viewing my page, but i don't see any events in the event tab ( both real time and behavior )

edit: when I add `ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign');` to frontend part it is working , but my backend custom events are not.

Answer (score 1):

In front end the syntax of the event should be similar like this:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign');
```

or like this:

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Videos',
  eventAction: 'play',
  eventLabel: 'Fall Campaign'
});
```

not only this:

```
ga('send', 'event');
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events?hl=en

So the problem is in how the event is constructed or the values ​​that are empty.

Comment: I see, thank you! I removed the `ga('send', 'event');` from frontend. Now I am only calling it from backend but it is the same